# Showing that the zeros of a sequence of functions converge in probability as the functions converge in probability

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $S_n$ be a sequence of random real-valued continuous functions defined on $\Theta\subset \mathbb{R}$, such that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $S_n(\theta)\overset{p}\rightarrow S(\theta)$ for every $\theta\in\Theta$, where $S$ is non-random. Suppose that for some $\theta_0$ in the interior of $\Theta$ and every $\epsilon>0$ small enough we have $$S(\theta_0 - \epsilon)<0<S(\theta_0 + \epsilon)$$ and that $S_n$ has exactly one zero $\hat{\theta}_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Deduce that $\hat{\theta}_n\overset{p}\rightarrow \theta_0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I have literally no idea where to start with this - I know the definition of convergence in probability, but I don't know what trick to employ to convert knowledge knowledge about the range of $S$ to knowledge about its domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $\epsilon > 0$, and $\eta > 0$ such that $S(\theta_0 - \epsilon)+ \eta < 0 <  S(\theta_0 + \epsilon) - \eta$.    If $|S_n(\theta_0 - \epsilon) - S(\theta_0 - \epsilon)| < \eta$ and $|S_n(\theta_0 + \epsilon) - S(\theta_0 + \epsilon)| < \eta$, then $S_n(\theta_0 - \epsilon) < 0 < S_n(\theta_0 + \epsilon)$, which implies that $\theta_0 - \epsilon < \hat{\theta}_n < \theta_0 + \epsilon$.  Since  $S_n(\theta_0 \pm \epsilon) \rightarrow ^P S(\theta_0 \pm \epsilon)$, the probability of this goes to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, and that says $\hat{\theta}_n \rightarrow^P \theta_0$.